# Stack around the variable 'res' was corrupted. Что это значит и что исправить в программе, чтобы этого избежатЬ?

Tags: c++

```
Программа считает количество делителей введенного числа. Но при вводе зависает, а после кидает исключения Stack around the variable 'res' was corrupted


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

const int max_len = 10000;
int osn = 10;

using namespace std;

struct BigInt
{
    int amount;     //количество цифр в числе
    int digits[max_len];    //массив цифр в обратном порядке

    void input()
    {
        memset(digits, 0, sizeof(digits));
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = str.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            digits[pos++] = str[i] - '0';
        amount = str.size();
    }

    void Output()
    {
        for (int i = amount - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            cout << digits[i];
    }
};


BigInt operator - (const BigInt &a, const BigInt &b)
{
    BigInt res = a;
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i<res.amount;i++)
    {
        res.digits[i] -= b.digits[i] + r;
        if (res.digits[i]<0)
        {
            res.digits[i] += osn;
            res.digits[i + 1]--;
        }
    }
    int pos = res.amount;
    while (pos && !res.digits[pos])
        pos--;
    res.amount = pos + 1;
    return res;
}

BigInt operator / (const BigInt &a, const int &n)
{
    BigInt res;
    res.amount = a.amount;
    int ost = 0;
    for (int i = res.amount - 1;i >= 0;i--)
    {
        int cur = ost * osn + a.digits[i];
        res.digits[i] = cur / n;
        ost = cur % n;
    }
    if (!res.digits[res.amount - 1] && res.amount != 1)
        res.amount--;
    return res;
}


bool operator != (const BigInt &delitel, const int zero)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < delitel.amount; i++)
    {
        if (delitel.digits[i] != zero)return true;
    }
    return false;
}


bool operator > (const BigInt & testDelimoe, const int zero)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < testDelimoe.amount;i++)
        if (testDelimoe.digits[i] > 0)return true;
    return false;
}


bool checkDelitel(BigInt testDelimoe)
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < testDelimoe.amount; i++)
    {
        if (testDelimoe.digits[i] != 0)flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

int main()
{
    BigInt delimoe;
    BigInt delitel;

    delimoe.input();
    delitel = delimoe / 2;

    int coldelitel = 0;

    int zero = 0;
    while (delitel / 2 != zero)
    {
        BigInt testDelimoe = delimoe;
        int arr[max_len];
        for (int i = 0; i < testDelimoe.amount; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = testDelimoe.digits[i];

        }
        while (testDelimoe > zero)
        {
            testDelimoe = testDelimoe - delitel;
            if (checkDelitel(testDelimoe))coldelitel++;
        }

        int pos = 0;
        delitel.digits[0] -= 1;
        while (delitel.digits[pos] < 0)
        {
            delitel.digits[pos + 1]--;
            delitel.digits[pos++] += 10;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Это значит [ровно то, что написано](https://translate.yandex.ru/?text=Stack%20around%20the%20variable%20'res'%20was%20corrupted&lang=en-ru). Для начала - избавьтесь от выделения на стеке таких объёмов данных (у вас как минимум - четырежды по `max_len * sizeof(int)`). Если проблема останется - ищите где выходите за границы массивов.

Comment: @PinkTux, поясните, как избавиться от выделения на стеке таких объемов

Comment: `int *digits = new int[max_length]` (и не забыть освободить в деструкторе, плюс добавить конструктор копирования). Ну а после этого - в отладчик, и прошагать хотя бы на небольших значениях.

Comment: @PinkTux, я только начинаю, можно чуть подробнее. Что значит освободить в деструкторе и добавить коструктор копирования?

Comment: @PinkTux а какие проблемы создаёт выделение больших объёмов данных на стеке ?

Comment: @ampawd, стек - не куча, он не резиновый. Например, MSDN сообщает: *For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the default stack size is 1 MB*. Учитывая, что часть его расходуется неявно на внутренние нужды (вызовы функций, передача аргументов, расходы внутри библиотечных функций и т.д.), выделять на стеке большие объёмы - не очень хорошая идея. Ну и в любом случае в данном коде он повреждаться может не только поэтому, нужно смотреть под отладчиком где ещё может запарываться стек. Или использовать кучу и отлаживаться под valgrind. Выход за границы массива - самая частая причина.